# Maximum events per session in Flurry Analytics

Tags: flurry

Is there a maximum amount of individual events that can be tracked in one session by Flurry Analytics?

We seem to have a block after 1000 events are logged in a user session - has this been observed elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Flurry confirmed there is a limit of 1000 events logged per user session